# Open X dialog boxes not at once but using common line of code

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have five div buttons and each one opens a dialog box. For each button I have make something like this into my jquery script...

```
$JQ_("#opener_1").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog("open");});
$JQ_("#opener_2").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_2").dialog("open");});
$JQ_("#opener_3").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_3").dialog("open");});
$JQ_("#opener_4").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_4").dialog("open");});
$JQ_("#opener_5").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_5").dialog("open");});
```

What I want to do is to use this part of code once and not five times, in my case. Any idea?

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="opener_1" class="opener_1">OPEN #1</div>
<div id="opener_2" class="opener_2">OPEN #2</div>
<div id="opener_3" class="opener_3">OPEN #3</div>
<div id="opener_4" class="opener_4">OPEN #4</div>
<div id="opener_5" class="opener_5">OPEN #5</div>

<div id="dialog_1" class="opener_1">OPEN #1</div>
<div id="dialog_2" class="opener_2">OPEN #2</div>
<div id="dialog_3" class="opener_3">OPEN #3</div>
<div id="dialog_4" class="opener_4">OPEN #4</div>
<div id="dialog_5" class="opener_5">OPEN #5</div>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $JQ_(function(){
    $JQ_('[id^="dialog"]').dialog({autoOpen:false,
                                      width:'auto',
                                     height:'auto',
                                  resizable:false,
                                       show:{effect:"fade", duration:250},
                                       hide:{effect:"fade", duration:250}
                                 });        
    $JQ_("#opener_1").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog("open");});
    $JQ_("#opener_2").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_2").dialog("open");});
    $JQ_("#opener_3").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_3").dialog("open");});
    $JQ_("#opener_4").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_4").dialog("open");});
    $JQ_("#opener_5").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_5").dialog("open");});
    });
```

**JSFIDDLE** Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/NjbZg/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

1) Using `this` to get the element that is being clicked.

```
$JQ_("[id^='opener_']").click(function(){
     console.log(this); //returns the element that is being click
   });
```

2) Get the **`id`** of the element being clicked and *split it to get the number* like this

```
this.id.split('_')[1]
```

3) Now bind this to your *dialog `id`* like

```
$JQ_("#dialog_" + this.id.split('_')[1]).dialog("open");});
```

---

You **final code** looks like

```
$JQ_("[id^='opener_']").click(function(){            
            $JQ_("#dialog_" + this.id.split('_')[1]).dialog("open");});        

    });
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NjbZg/2/)

Comment: @GreenMadness Its my pleasure to help you friend :)